# .htaccess 301 redirect by removing a directory from URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I like to do a 301 redirect

http://abc.com/category/category/duplex 
to
http://abc.com/category/duplex

using .htaccess
Google shows a lot of crawl errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_alias and RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/category/(.*)$ /category/$1
```